# Using Django to show a csv pandas file in html

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, pandas

Building a site using Django. I am trying to show the information of a csv file in html. 
I am trying to arrange the file through python `pandas`. 
There are no errors being thrown up however what's contained in the file is not being shown.
In the code below I am trying to display the printed result from the pandas in my html file.

My python file:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('faults.csv')
printed = print(df)

def reader(str):
file = str + '.csv'
return file
```

My `html` page:

```
<a href={% url 'thehomepage' %}>go back to the home page</a>
<p>{{ input_from_home_page }}</p>
<p>{{ printed }}</p>
```

`About.html`[image: about html]
  [image: index html]
  [image: my py file]

Comment: show us your full Django view, it does feel going through tutorial would be beneficiary for you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: @iklinac thanks for the tutorial. i have added in screen shout of the project. i still cannot figure out why its not appearing in on the site.